# object reference set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

I make richtextbox disable by choosing "cleared" on a combobox, and I get this error "object reference set to an instance of an object"

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Cleared")
        {
            richTextBox1.Enabled = false;
            richTextBox1.Text = "";
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception a)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(a.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean **not** set?

Comment: On which line is the error?

Comment: Can `comboBox1.SelectedItem` be `null`?

Comment: comboBox1.SelectedItem is probably null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21737654/2864740 (I wrote this now, just for you.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems unlikely that `richTextBox1` is `null` (since it's probably given a value as initialization), the only other possibility is that `comboBox1.SelectedItem` is `null`.  The simplest fix would be to check for `null`:

```
    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null && comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Cleared")
    {
        richTextBox1.Enabled = false;
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null && comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Cleared")
```